# What is the best way to display a large set of items in a recycler view from a network request?

Tags: android, kotlin, pagination, get, retrofit

I'm experimenting with a movie API (https://developers.themoviedb.org/3/) and I need some advice on what direction I should take to display its data in a RecyclerView.

For example, I want to get a list of popular movies from the API (https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular) using Retrofit and show them in a recycler view but a single call only returns 20 items/movies. When the user scrolls to the bottom of the recyclerview, I want the next page of 20 items to be loaded and so on. There are 10000 items in total and 500 pages. I know I can change the **page** query string to request the next 20 items but I don't know how I should design my app to achieve this. Should I use the Android pagination library? Should I do synchronous requests in a loop?

I've taken a long look at the Android pagination library but I'm confused about how to use it for what I want.

Please help :)

Comment: The Paging library is generally the recommended way to do this. Do you have a specific thing you're confused about that I can help clear up? The high-level is that you want call `PagingDataAdapter.submitData(PagingData)`, and you get a `PagingData` from a `Pager`.

Comment: Thanks for commenting @dlam
I guess I'm particularly confused with the different load types (APPEND, PREPEND, REFRESH). I'm not really sure what I should do for each one. I think I understand the purpose of REFRESH and APPEND but not PREPEND. When would I want to prepend data ??

Comment: RemoteMediator overall is pretty confusing to me

Comment: In cases where your initial load (REFRESH) isn't loading the first page you'll need to support PREPEND. Or.. you may want to support page dropping to prevent memory pressure from very long lists. Another example would be to support state restoration or fast scrolling (like scrolling to a specific letter in a long contacts list, its better to just skip loading pages for contacts with names starting with A-R and and immediately start loading from S, etc.) These are just a few examples, but hopefully shows it's needed.

Comment: RemoteMediator is used to load from layered sources, when you're combining Network + DB (or similar), it's just a way to receive callbacks at boundary conditions when one source of data runs out and you need to query the other. So when PagingSource APPENDs everything you've got in DB, Paging will ask RemoteMediator (if provided) to load with type == APPEND and its your job as the implementer to query the network for more data, write it to DB then invalidate your PagingSource to tell Pager to pick up the changes.

Comment: Btw, have you had a chance to view the documentation available on d.android.com/paging3? If you have any feedback about it being confusing, please file an issue here to help those after you! https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=413106&template=1096385

Comment: Thanks for your help dlam. That clears up some of my confusion